# How to show/hide an element based on the presence of vertical scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I want to show a div only if the page has scrollbars, and hide it if not. I want to do this in either pure CSS or JavaScript (if impossible in CSS).

I've found a question on Stack Exchange, but it's infested with that garbage jQuery cancer, so it's useless. I'm talking about pure JavaScript -- not jCancer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JS solution, using this function:

```
const isScrollable = elem => elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
```

**Edit (description):**
The function returns `true` if the element is scrollable, `false` otherwise.

**Example:**

```js
const isScrollable = elem => elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;

// make scrollable divs have a red border
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
  if (isScrollable(div)) div.style.borderColor = "red";
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

div#div1 {
  height: 100px;
}

div#div2 {
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras maximus arcu quis mi eleifend tristique. Curabitur convallis tellus eget volutpat luctus. Fusce molestie molestie ante, vel fermentum erat. Fusce tempor erat eget dolor ultrices interdum. Pellentesque sed placerat nulla. Duis consequat, lorem quis vehicula lacinia, libero leo tincidunt odio, et porta ex turpis malesuada lorem. Proin sapien metus, facilisis sed urna non, vehicula commodo velit. Etiam venenatis laoreet neque vel sollicitudin. Suspendisse lacinia, lectus hendrerit dapibus laoreet, dui lorem condimentum enim, a vulputate ex ipsum ut nibh.
</div>

<div id="div2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras maximus arcu quis mi eleifend tristique. Curabitur convallis tellus eget volutpat luctus. Fusce molestie molestie ante, vel fermentum erat.
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work. No matter if I send "window", "html", "body", "document.body", etc., it never returns anything but false.

Comment: If it returns false, it must mean the elements you passed aren't scrollable. Also, ```window``` is not an element in the DOM. And the ```window``` object has no such property ```head``` or ```body```. But passing ```document.body``` is fine.